# Reverting ASP SQL DataSource Select statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

If the Select statement has been specified on the .aspx page, and then later altered in the code-behind, based on some event-driven logic, is there a way to revert the select statement to what is originally on the .aspx page?

The ASP code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds_Users" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Users]"  >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In the codebehind:

```
ds_Users.SelectStatement += " WHERE [UserType] LIKE '" + LocalVariable + "'";
```

Let's assume the above event was bound to a filter combobox that has the `UserTypes` as items.

If there's a "View All" option included in that list, how would I revert the `SelectStatement` to the original query without storing the Select statement (`SELECT * FROM [Users]`) as another string in the code-behind. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to always fix the SQL Select Command, on every page load, or on post back. You do bind ones, and then again only if you click on a button that change the SQL command.

Here is an example, please note `gvMyLista` is the GridView that use the data.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FixTheSelectCommand();
}

void FixTheSelectCommand()
{
    // this is an example - make your test here to know if there is a valid variable
    if(LocalVariable != null)
        ds_Users.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [UserType] LIKE '" + LocalVariable + "'";
    else
        ds_Users.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [Users]";

    if (!IsPostBack)
        gvMyLista.DataBind();
}

// when a search button clicked that change the search text
protected void btnSearchFor_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    gvMyLista.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid having the select command on the ASP page and then duplicating it on the code-behind for that specific event.

Comment: @Daniel then avoid it - with the code I write you can do that - (up to a point)

Comment: sorry if that response seemed short, that was not my intention. Do you even bother specifying the SelectCommand on the ASP page? I'm trying to avoid duplicating a string that may cause issues if all instances aren't updated when a change is needed

Comment: @Daniel You can leave the aspx part with out any sql command, and use only the code behind for that - the problem is that on every post back you need to set again the SelectCommand - now, if you have a GridView for example that make paging - you must set again the SelectCommand on every post back that paging does , with out DataBind().

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've noted the need for the binding on postback.